# stuttering animation

Tags: rigging

[image]

This is the animation(which is terrible) that stutters. You can see it if you look the arms closely. I'm quite new to rigging and this has been the 4th try however whenever I spend days or a week to finish one I throw it away because of these glitchy movements. I tried the graph editor to somehow fix it but sometimes this doesn't necessarily helps since not always I'll have the exact graph shape. Such as trying to get a certain value at time A yet messing up the value in time B which originally I was totally fine of. When I was first confronted to this problem I made keyframes for every single frame. It was a disaster both in time and performance. And even if I do manage to make it perfectly, I suppose this isn't what everybody does? I just wanted to have some faster solution or a proper one. Technically I could make a perfect animation by spending weeks but I think that'll lead us nowhere. 
How do you guys manage these problems?

[image]

This is the keyframes I added in. I think this is a legitimate amount but what are your thoughts?

Comment: I would call this a single jerk motion rather than a stutter, for this comment. You probably want to know at what frame you see the single jerk motion.  Blender can annotate your render with frame numbers.  I suggest you do this for the benefit of the reader.  Often times to create the cycle you want the first and last frames to be the same pose.  There is copy and paste pose.  That is only half the problem.  You need to make sure the keyframes implied by the repeat keyframes has the timing desired.

Comment: Make sure the timing around the jerk motion is not too fast.  Archive your work and spread the poses in the failed area more to match the successful motion.  What technique did you use to create the cycle? Only video repeat or something else? As a reader I cannot tell if you used the NLA Editor or is the GIF or other video is creating jerk motion at the endpoints.  Or is the jerk motion happening expressly happening in the middle?

Comment: You want the join of the first and last frame with keyframes to have  a well spaced join rather like the successful portion of the animation, not congested.  Sometimes you may want to to have a keyframe at the end be a halfway pose (50%..90%) so the repeat is smooth.  You can copy and paste your keyframes for a double cycle to see if the problems only occurs when you repeat by video or is it the joining of first and last frames.

Comment: You can use a cycles modifier on your armature to see if your keyframes are correctly chosen to your standards.  You do not even need to see the body and uniform of your character.  Just view the armature. With the frame number annotations this well tell the reader more.  Then you can state in a sentence ... at frame X  is the problem or ... the repeat of my armature poses creates a problem.  Think about the timing created by repetition.

Comment: Even more drastic.  Archive your file and work with a copy.  Animate the armature only.  Hide the body and uniform.  Keep the floor and maybe shoes.  Delete previous keyframe work.  Animate again the armature with keyframes.  Use cycles modifier on keyframes.  Inspect the walk timing often and do quick renders in the simplest and fastest smallest serviceable render possible.  Your second time around maybe easier and quicker.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I appreciate the time you invested in and I didn't notice this until now. Sorry for that. 1."What technique did you use to create the cycle?" ==> I just copy and pasted the first pose to the last frame and added interval frames. Such as the frame at which the foot contacts with the ground. then I adjusted with the graph editor. 2."Or is the jerk motion happening expressly happening in the middle?' ==> Yes it is. About at frame 40 out of 64. The whole 64 frame is a loop.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger 3. "You want the join of the first and last frame with keyframes to have a well spaced join rather like the successful portion of the animation, not congested" ==> Well do you mean I shouldn't make the frame 0 motion be the same with the last frame motion? To add some in between? I actually have no problem with the end/start of the loop. It looks nice and smooth.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Ok, I'll try using cycles modifier. I'll edit the original post of repost.

Comment: If you render the armature with the frame annotation the reader and you can see the frame range with the flaw.   Frame annotation is just a click on the correct panel for output. Clothes / Uniform not necessary.  Low quality quick render is more important than your current animation.  The viewer [right side] clearly has too much snap/jerk motion.  Show an isolated graph window with the shoulder.  The hyper snappy range you mentioned  was near frame 40. Focus on those and the shape of the curve . Smooth the speed out ... minimize the maximum acceleration with the curve and the range of motion.